# Sort tuple by last name

Tags: python

For my python homework one of the questions is: "Write a complete python program that reads a file with comma separated fields with first name, last name, and number. The program then prints them in order sorted by last name. Remember for sorting on tuples you might need (key=lambda tup: tup[x]) where x is the field." Normally I don't like asking for direct help on my homework but I don't even know where to start on this one, although I'll attempt it:

```
t=open('tlash.txt', 'r')
tup=t.readlines()
tup[2]
tup.sort()
print(tup)
```

So this will open the file, read the lines, then the second field in each line of the tuple will be sorted. Should that work?

EDIT: I didn't think to make my own file to test on lol, brainfart. I also forgot to define the tup :p But anyways when I sort it now it goes in alphabetical order by first name. I'm not sure how to get it to sort by the second field?

EDIT 2: I also forgot about how indices work, dumb mistake! After seeing where I was messing up I reworked my code to the following and it works, thanks all!

```
t=open('trash.txt', 'r')
tup=t.readlines()
tup.sort(key=lambda x:x.split(',')[1])
print(tup)
```

Comment: *Should that work?* Try it yourself!! :)

Comment: do you expect python to know what `tup[2]` is without first assigning something to `tup`?

Comment: Remember indices start at 0, so "second" == 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('trash.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in sorted(fin, key=lambda x:x.split(',')[1]):
        print line
```

Comment: Nice solution! Off-topic: I remember the first time i saw your answer you're in 80.3k XD

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by last name, and assuming last name is the second column:

```
with open('trash.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.split(",") for line in f]
    sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

@gnibbler's answer beats mine. I'm storing it in the memory, so this is inefficient for large files.

Comment: use `itemgetter`, it will be faster for big files, I guess.